# Let calendar start at right day

Tags: php, html

I created a table, to work as a calendar, but every month starts at Monday. I want it to start at the right day. Here's the code, if it isn't clear I'll try to explain further. Thank you in advance. The PHP code is to highlight the current day, and to echo the current month.

```
<table id="calender"> 
<tr>
<th colspan="7" id="month-wrap"> <font id="month"> <?php echo date("F"); ?> </font> </th>
</tr>
<tr>

<td class="days"> <strong> Maandag </strong> </td>
<td class="days"> <strong> Dinsdag </strong> </td>
<td class="days"> <strong> Woensdag </strong> </td>
<td class="days"> <strong> Donderdag </strong> </td>
<td class="days"> <strong> Vrijdag </strong> </td>
<td class="days"> <strong> Zaterdag </strong> </td>
<td class="days"> <strong> Zondag </strong> </td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 1) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 1 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 2) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 2 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 3) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 3 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 4) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 4 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 5) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 5 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 6) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 6 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 7) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 7 </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 8) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 8 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 9) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 9 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 10) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 10 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 11) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 11</td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 12) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 12 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 13) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 13</td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 14) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 14 </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 15) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 15 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 16) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 16</td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 17) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 17 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 18) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 18 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 19) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 19 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 20) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 20 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 21) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 21 </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 22) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 22 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 23) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 23 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 24) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 24 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 25) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 25 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 26) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 26 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 27) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 27 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 28) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 28 </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 29) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 29 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 30) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 30 </td>
<td id="<?= (date("j") == 31) ? 'date-selected' : ' ' ?>"> 31 </td>
<td> <font class="hidden"> 1 </font></td>
<td> <font class="hidden"> 2 </font></td>
<td> <font class="hidden"> 3 </font></td>
<td> <font class="hidden"> 4 </font></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Find the number of days in the month [date('t')], and start a counter loop that will end at that number.  Set up a 7-count loop.  Run through the days of the week and compare them to the first day of the month; if they're the same, start printing.    Alternatively, do something hackish with the system calendar ;)

Comment: What have you tried to get this going? Seeing your attempts to solve the problem will help us to provide you with a better answer.

Comment: @Henders I haven't tried anything yet. i cant come up with anything that I am able to do.

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey But how do I make it so it outputs everything else from that moment on in the correct order.